# Windows - LAMP running on CentOS

Tags: windows, centos, virtual-machine, lamp

I have successfully installed Apache, MariaDB(MySQL), and PHP on a CentOS distribution on a VMWare Virtual Drive. All services are currently running.

When I run the 'hostname' command in CentOS, localhost.localdomain is returned. If I enter this (or localhost.localdomain:80) in the Chrome address bar on my Windows 10.1 OS, it skips to the IIS Windows Internet Information Services page.

How can I access my LAMP stack on my CentOS virtual machine from my Windows physical machine?

Thanks,

A

Comment: no surprise there. "localhost" is ONE of the names for every single internet-capable device out there. it literally is just a name that means "talk to myself". when you enter "localhost" on your windows box, you're talking to the windows box. You can't reach the "localhost" of some OTHER box from the outside. You need the IP and or network hostname of that lamp machine, and that will NOT be "localhost".

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1. Enter the IP ADDRESS of your virtual machine in the address bar of the web browser.

Solution 2. Modify the Windows hosts file to move to the IP ADDRESS of your virtual machine for the specific host name.